# Catching error in Powershell and rewriting output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to craft a script to resolve a long list of domain names to IP addresses.  Some of these aren't defined and I need to catch the error and just return a "blank value."  In the script below, I tried doing this using a basic If/Then, but I still get a wordy error (at the bottom) rather than just a blank value.  Any ideas how to get around this?  I really appreciate it!

----- SCRIPT -----

```
$names = Get-Content C:\temp\names.txt
ForEach ($name in $names) {
$ipAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$name")[0].IPAddressToString;
if ($ipAddress) {
    Write-Host $name"-"$ipAddress 
    }
else {
    Write-Host $name"-"
     }
}
```

---- OUTPUT/ERROR ----

```
mydomain.com-1.2.3.4
yourdomain.com-4.3.2.1
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"
anotherdomain.com-5.5.5.5
```

---- What I'd Like to See -----

```
mydomain.com-1.2.3.4
yourdomain.com-4.3.2.1
NOTDEFINEDDOMAIN.tld-
anotherdomain.com-5.5.5.5
```

---- HERE'S THE SOLUTION THAT WORKED - THANK YOU!----

```
$names = Get-Content C:\temp\names.txt

ForEach ($name in $names) {
Try {
    $ipAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$name")[0].IPAddressToString;
    Write-Host $name"-"$ipAddress
    }
Catch {
    Write-Host $name"-"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is weird.. I can't reproduce the exception calling `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("doesnotexit")[0].IPAddressToString;` What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Hi Nick - I'm using version 5.  I ran the above and got the error again...

Comment: Even stranger!! I'm on version 5 as well. Hmmm...

Comment: Yea, I don't know what's going on. Even passing a $null in doesn't cause an exception... `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($null)[0].IPAddressToString;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update of answer:**

> Catching error in Powershell and rewriting output
>
> I need to catch the error and just return a "blank value

Use try/catch:

```
$names = Get-Content C:\temp\names.txt
ForEach ($name in $names)
{
   try
   {
      $ipAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$name")[0].IPAddressToString;
      Write-Host $name"-"$ipAddress 
   }
   catch
   {
       Write-Host $name"-"
       $_.Exception.Message   # <- Check this to read and rewrite exception message
   }
}
```

> ---- What I'd Like to See -----

If you want - you can manipulate of exception message like as string - this is line to get message in catch block:

`$_.Exception.Message`

Other way to get info about errors is `$Error` variable (it's the array/list of errors)...

More information:

- http://vwiki.co.uk/Exceptions_and_Error_Handling_(PowerShell)
- [PowerShell Tutorial – Try Catch Finally and error handling in PowerShell](http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell)
- [Using PowerShell $Error variable](http://maxtblog.com/2012/07/using-powershell-error-variable/)
- [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx)

**Update 2:**

I forgot about one thing - try/catch working only with terminating errors.
I'm not sure about type of error in your case (because can't reproduce it), however sometimes you may want to add to your command:

`-Error Stop`

Comment: hehe... so what is the question ? As far I understand - the subject is `Catching error in Powershell and rewriting output` and the question is `I need to catch the error and just return a "blank value`... So in my opinion answer is simple... `use try/chatch`. However I have update my answer to give some example and links - I hope this help more.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz.  After a little reading I realized how simple the try/catch is and implemented it as shown in my edited original question.  Thanks again!